# In XML, Can CData exist alongside another node?

Tags: xml, cdata

Is this a valid XML?

```
<foo>
    <![CDATA[<bar>]]>
    <sibling></sibling>
</foo>
```

Can all XML Parsers parse this?

Answer (score 1):

CData alongside other node is fine, it doesn't break well-formed-ness of the XML document. Given that fact, all decent XML parser should be able to parse such structure.

From XML 1.0 specification :

> [Definition: [**CDATA sections**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-cdsection) **may occur anywhere [character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-chardata) may occur**; they are used to escape blocks of text containing characters which would otherwise be recognized as markup. CDATA sections begin with the string `" <![CDATA[ "` and end with the string `" ]]> "`:].

Answer (score 0):

That XML fragment is certainly well formed. Whether it is valid depends on the XML schema (or DTD) that you use to validate it.